# Java Server / Client Trouble

Tags: java, arraylist

So here is the question we were given:

> You are given the following application-layer networking protocol for a simple client/server application.
>
> A client can send tokens (words) to the server which adds them to a global tokens list in memory. The tokens list has a capacity of 10 different tokens. The tokens should be stored in the tokens list in descending (reverse) lexicographical order. 
>   There are three types of requests: SUBMIT, REMOVE and
>   QUIT.
>
> The protocol in detail:
>
> - Client request (a message send from client to server): SUBMIT token
>     Server: If the tokens list is not yet full, add the token to the global list of tokens (if the list doesn’t
>     contain that token yet) or ignore it (if the respective token was already in the list). In both cases,
>     respond by sending message OK to the client. If the list is already full (contains 10 tokens), respond
>     to the client with message ERROR.
>     token stands for a string which doesn’t contain whitespace, see class Scanner (Java API).
>     The tokens list should be sorted in descending lexicographical order at any time. Choose an
>     appropriate data structure for representing the tokens list.
> - Client request: REMOVE token
>     Server: If the tokens list contains token, remove it from the tokens list and reply to the client with
>     message OK. Otherwise, reply with ERROR.
> - Client request: QUIT
>     Server: Ends the connection to that client. No response.
>
> Q1. Create a (non-enterprise-, non-servlet-) Java class for a server which can interact with clients via
>   the Internet in compliance with the given protocol. 
>   Do not support concurrent handling of clients here, just the sequential dealing with clients (that is,
>   only after the connection to a client has ended, a new client can connect to the server, and so on).
>   The server should maintain only a single, global tokens list which is never emptied by the server
>   unless by means of REMOVE requests (i.e., not a new empty tokens list for each connecting client).

And here is my attempt so far:

public class Server {

```
private Socket s;
private Scanner in;
private PrintWriter out;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6789);
    Server serverInstance = new Server();
    System.out.println("Server running. Waiting for a client to connect...");
    while(true) {
        serverInstance.s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        serverInstance.run();
        System.out.println("Client disconnected. Waiting for a new client to connect...");
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        try {
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            doService(); // the actual service
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
public void doService() throws IOException {
    while(true) {
        if(!in.hasNext())
            return;
        String request = in.next();
        System.out.println("Request received: " + request);
        // (...) test for type of request here (not implemented)
        Request(request);
    }
}
public void Request(String request) {
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    String amountStr = in.next();
    if(request.startsWith("SUBMIT")) {
        if(tokens.size() <= 10){
            out.println(tokens.add(amountStr)); //server response
            System.out.println( amountStr + " added to list");
        }
        else{System.out.println("Error");
        } 
    }
    else if(request.startsWith("REMOVE")) {
    out.println(tokens.remove(amountStr)); //server response
    System.out.println(amountStr + " removed from list");
    } 
    else if(request.equals("QUIT")){
    System.err.println("Program ended");
    }

    System.out.println(tokens);
    out.flush();
    }
}
```

public class Client {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
     InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
     OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();
     Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
     String request = "SUBMIT hello \n";
     out.print(request);
     out.flush();
     String response = in.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Token: " + response);
     s.close();
    }
```

}

> Output:
>
> Server running. Waiting for a client to connect...
>
> Client connected
>
> Request received: SUBMIT
>
> hello added to list
>
> [hello]
>
> Client disconnected. Waiting for a new client to connect...
>
> Client connected
>
> Request received: SUBMIT
>
> hi added to list
>
> [hi]
>
> Client disconnected. Waiting for a new client to connect...

So I have got the server working and the client can connect to it and SUBMIT a token to the arraylist, but every time a new client adds a token to the list it just replaces the old one instead of adding to the array. [hi] replaces [hello] instead of becoming [hello, hi].

For the REMOVE and QUIT requests I don't really have an idea how to get them working correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that it's because you declare a new `ArrayList` every time a client asks for the service. you call `run`, wich calls `Request`, wich declares a fresh `ArrayList` every time.

PS: change the name of the `Request` method, should start with lowercase: `request()`

Comment: Forgot to give you a possible solution: just declare your `ArrayList` as a class variable instead of declaring it as local of the method `request`

Comment: Thank you, the SUBMIT and REMOVE are now working pretty well.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to get the QUIT working correctly?

Comment: mmm... make `request` return a `boolean`, so it returns `false` when `QUIT` is received. Then make your `while(true)` on `doService` as follows: ` boolean keep=true; while(keep) {
        if(!in.hasNext())
            return;
        String request = in.next();
        System.out.println("Request received: " + request);
        // (...) test for type of request here (not implemented)
        keep=Request(request);
    }`  in theory this will terminate the loop, make your `doService`return to `run()` and finish it.

Comment: @Dani Remember to put that in the answer, not just in something that happens to be near the answer.